# ExpressionEngine website not caching on Cloudflare

Tags: ee2

I am having problems getting my ExpressionEngine website to cache on Cloudflare.

I am running:
- ExpressionEngine 2.11.7
- PHP 5.4 / MySQL 5.5
- IIS 7.0.

Let me run through steps I am taking:

- On Cloudflare, I have the rule *.domain.com/* to be cached i.e. everything is being cached.
- After doing curl -I on https://www.domain.com/ I noticed the response was coming back with cf-cache-status: MISS. I then tried https://www.domain.com/page/ and I got the same response. /page/ is a template created inside ExpressionEngine.

  - If I create a test page https://www.domain.com/cachetest.php i.e. not ExpressionEngine, it caches that page absolutely fine. So it isn't an IIS configuration, and it isn't the web server, or otherwise I would expect that page not to cache.
  - my web.config file strips out index.php, which I thought might have caused the issue, but I have tried with and without that rule but still not working.
  - I have checked over my output caching in IIS and although caching is enabled, there are no rules. As a 'to be sure', I disabled caching to test again.

Am I missing something? Is there a setting that could be preventing Cloudflare to cache the website for some reason? I have no issues with Wordpress sites using Cloudflares cache, using the same settings.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT
I've just found this on the Cloudflares support page (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-):

> or if there is a cookie in the response, then Cloudflare will not cache the resource.

If I look at the response in Curl, well we see the exp_last_visit, exp_last_activity, exp_tracker, exp_csrf_token cookies in the response headers.

So does this mean we cannot use ExpressionEngine with Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it - in Cloudflare, you need to also enable Edge Cache TTL on the same rule. But be sure to disable for your admin pages!

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to switch to feeding cloudflare with a static cache version of EE: the static pages won't hit your EE server at all, and so you shouldn't have a problem with cookies for those pages.

An easy way to get this working is to use the static cache features of [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash), [Mustache](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mustash) for automatic cache clearing rules, and the free [Cloudflare module for Stash](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mustash-cloudflare).

HTH

Comment: Ooo great, thank you for this - I will have a look now.